# Formatting a data binding before displaying in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Bit of a noob question in trying to get my head around knockoutjs. If I have the below markup and javascript. What is the right place to make the change (markup or script), in order to make it so instead of only the price being shown in the third column of a row, I display the price prefixed by the currencySymbol? Thanks a ton.

Markup:

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: meal().mealName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0, currencySymbol: "$"},
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95, currencySymbol: "$"},
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290, currencySymbol: "$"}    ];       
    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Comment: The Q&A are two consecutive steps of a tutorial, so this doesn't makes senses as a Q&A

Answer (score 0):

So I jumped the gun and should of just trusted the tutorial to answer the question. We updated the SeatReservation function from:

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}
```

to:

```
//include currency reference and fix price to two decimal places
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.meal().currencySymbol + self.meal().price.toFixed(2);            
    });    
}
```

finally the third row markup should be updated from:

```
<td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
```

to:

```
<td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
```